# Drupal menu_primary_links() not returning primary links menu on some pages

Tags: php, drupal

I am using Drupal 6.8 and I noticed on some pages menu_primary_links() is returning a empty array on some pages. Is there a setting I have overlooked?

Thanks.

Comment: You should really update your Drupal installation to the latest which currently is 6.15. You would get a lot of bugfixes and security fixes doing this.

Answer (score 0):

Also is there there such a function to get a specific menu?

Comment: Please don't answer your own question unless you are actually answering the question. You are, however, free to edit your question as many times as you like.